# Why can't I loop through an array?

Tags: php, foreach

I get these numbers seperated by commas from a textarea but I get an error when I try to loop through them. How do I do it? This is my code:

```
$numbers = $_GET['numbers'];

foreach($numbers as $number){
echo $number;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET['numbers']` is an array? Apparently it is not. Do `var_dump($_GET['numbers'])` and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first make an array out of `$numbers`. You can do this by adding this line:

```
$numbers = explode(',', $_GET['numbers']);
```

Then, before you use them in the `foreach` loop you should use `trim()` to remove whitespace from the start and end:

```
foreach($numbers as $number){
    $number = trim($number);

    echo $number
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `$_GET['numbers']` is a comma-separated list, it's not an array.

```
foreach(explode(",",$_GET['numbers']) as $number)
```